# How to export database with data in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, export

How can I export my 2012 database with data to a .sql file so I can import it to a 2008 server? I've never been able to export the data only the structure.

Comment: . . If the database is small, then the SSMS "create scripts" wizard has an option to export the data as well.  Just look on the "advanced" tab to find the right option.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can right click on the database in management studio.
then go to,

```
Tasks --> Generate scripts --> Advanced
```

There you can enable *"Type of data to script"* as `Schema and data`, then generate the script. So that your script file will be populated with your data in table.

Comment: It is not working well when there is a Text type column inside binary data. It was scripted INSERT as unicode text so at restore makes error!
(Visual FoxPro uses "memo" columns for this type of data and it is translated to "text" in SQL Server)

Comment: I'm not understanding the structure of your data. Please share your table structure and a sample data.

Comment: I just made a sample:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IKTCS](
 [IKTSSZ] [float] NOT NULL,
 [CSMEGNEV] [char](254) NULL,
 [CSITTCSATT] [char](254) NULL,
 [CSFILE] [text] NULL,
 [CSUTV] [char](254) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[IKTCS] ([IKTSSZ], [CSMEGNEV], [CSITTCSATT], [CSFILE], [CSUTV]) VALUES (1, N'file', NULL, N'EßŁŁB†B÷BňBóB‚matroskaB‡B…S€g  /Ă?ËM›tÂM»ŚS«„', NULL)

Comment: This is a working script. You should imagine in the TEXT some special binary what contains 'characters' what made the script unworkable. I didn't made investigation what code doing this situation.

Comment: Also under Advanced, make sure you set Script for Server Version to SQL Server 2008.

Comment: If you have the Generate Scripts wizard, you won't see Advanced until about the third screen in.

Comment: That "Advanced" button sure can be hard to find 